# How to add multiple conditions check in global Charts file in Helm

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I want to install a chart only if my both conditions are satisfied. Basically I want to use **and** condition here. I've tried multiple permutations but none of them seems to be working.
What I want should look something like this.

```
- name: chart-test
  version: 0.1.0
  condition: global.test1.enabled and global.test2.enabled
```

If test1 is enabled and test2 is enabled then only chart-test should be installed. If any one of them is set to false then it shouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Helm `condition:` and `tags:` controls](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#tags-and-condition-fields-in-dependencies) don't allow Boolean logic at all, and effectively only allow "or" combinations.  That is, you could write

```yaml
condition: global.test1.enabled, global.test2.enabled
```

and it would install the dependency if *either* value is set; but this is the only syntax Helm supports, and there's no way to only install the dependency if *both* are set.

Comment: Yes I also checked their documentation and tried above one. But this is not what I wanted. I've also tried if conditions but it is also throwing error. Can't we use if conditions in helm charts?
`
{{- if eq .Values.global.test2.enabled true }}
*/ chart content */
{{- end}}
`

Error I got, cannot load Chart.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: did not find expected node content

Comment: You cannot use any sort of conditional or templating in the `Chart.yaml` or `requirements.yaml` files beyond the specific things mentioned in the linked documentation.